# How can I show the statement: "every Cauchy sequence converges" can replace the completeness axiom?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I saw a theorem in my textbook that they claim the statement: "every Cauchy sequence converges" can replace the completeness axiom (the fact that every bounded sequence has a least upper bound). In fact, they claimed that this was possible in either direction, but my book only supplied the direction from the completeness axiom to the fact every Cauchy sequence converges and claimed the other direction could "easily be shown"

I have been trying, rather slowly, to show how the fact that every Cauchy sequence converges necessarily implies the completeness axiom. However, I am not sure how to proceed as the completeness axiom is an axiom and thus I have trouble with formulating an argument actually "proving it". Would anyone happen to know how I may prove this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by 'the completeness axiom'?

Comment: Order completeness, as he said, every upper bounded set has a supremum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the upper bound and some element of the set, you form an initial interval $[a_0,b_0]$. By bisection then construct a decreasing sequence of intervals $[a_k,b_k]$ so that $b_k$ is an upper bound and the interval contains an element of the set.

Since the sequences $a_k$ and $b_k$ are monotone and bounded, they are Cauchy and by the topological completeness axiom convergent. Now apply standard arguments to show that the common limit is the supremum of the set.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is true. Convergence of Cauchy sequences is weaker than the Supremum property.

Only if you additionally assume the archimedean property, the Supremum property follows from the convergence of Cauchy sequences. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers.

The proof in the other answer uses that monotone and bounded sequences are Cauchy sequences which also need not be true for non archimedean fields.